# Построение столбчатой диаграммы с категориями

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, визуализация

Помогите с построением диаграммы. имеются два DataFrame со следующими данными:

```
     num_room      cost
7        1.0  191892.0
8        1.0  186047.0
9        1.0  175676.0
18       2.0  111062.0
38       3.0  200000.0
39       4.0  168224.0

      num_room      cost
0        1.0  177419.0
1        1.0  188710.0
2        1.0  198387.0
3        1.0  193548.0
4        1.0  198387.0
5        1.0  184615.0
6        1.0  194118.0
10       2.0  130952.0
```

В первом DataFrame собраны данные(num_room, cost) для квартир расположенных не выше 5 этажа, во втором данные(num_room, cost) для квартир выше 5 этажа.
Как получить столбчатую диаграмму, чтобы по осям лежали значения num_room (ось Х) и cost (ось Y), и было два столбца разного цвета один столбец для квартир не выше пятого, второй для квартир выше пятого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае я бы воспользовался [seaborn.barplot()](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

сначала я бы добавил столбец с типом квартиры:

```
d1['type'] = 'below 5 fl.'
d2['type'] = '5 fl. or higher'
```

потом объединил `d1` и `d2` в один DF:

```
df = pd.concat([d1, d2])
```

Получилось:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
    num_room      cost             type
7        1.0  191892.0      below 5 fl.
8        1.0  186047.0      below 5 fl.
9        1.0  175676.0      below 5 fl.
18       2.0  111062.0      below 5 fl.
38       3.0  200000.0      below 5 fl.
39       4.0  168224.0      below 5 fl.
0        1.0  177419.0  5 fl. or higher
1        1.0  188710.0  5 fl. or higher
2        1.0  198387.0  5 fl. or higher
3        1.0  193548.0  5 fl. or higher
4        1.0  198387.0  5 fl. or higher
5        1.0  184615.0  5 fl. or higher
6        1.0  194118.0  5 fl. or higher
10       2.0  130952.0  5 fl. or higher
```

График:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x='num_room', y='cost', hue='type', data=df)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: MaxU, большое спасибо. То что надо) Черные штрихи, что обозначают?

Comment: @ИльяСидаш, всегда рад помочь :-) Черные штрихи - это "error bar", чтобы убрать добавьте параметр `errwidth=0`